# How to get the corresponding json data in different { } and [ ] (using Python)?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to use Python Flask to process JSON data.
Here is what my data looks like:

```
[
    {   'className': 'BoardGame', 
        'fields': {
            'objectId': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'playerName': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'cheatMode': {'type': 'Boolean'}, 
            'score': {'type': 'Number'}, 
            'updatedAt': {'type': 'Date'}, 
            'createdAt': {'type': 'Date'}
        }, 
        'classLevelPermissions': {
            'addField': {'*': True}, 
            'create': {'*': True}, 'get': {'*': True}, 
            'update': {'*': True}, 'find': {'*': True}, 
            'delete': {'*': True}
        }
    }, 
    {   'className': 'RPGGAme', 
        'fields': {
            'objectId': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'GameId': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'robotName': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'updatedAt': {'type': 'Date'}, 
            'createdAt': {'type': 'Date'}
        }, 
        'classLevelPermissions': {
            'addField': {'*': True}, 
            'create': {'*': True}, 'get': {'*': True}, 
            'fields': {'*': True}, 'find': {'*': True}, 
            'delete': {'*': True}
        }
    }
]
```

The problem is that I cannot get the corresponding data due to the complex format of `[]` and `{}`

**Here is what I want:**

```
[0]["className"]: "BoardGame" <---String
[0]["fields"]: ["objectId","playerName","cheatMode"....] <-- List Of String
[1]["className"]: "RPGGame"    <---String
[1]["fields"]: ["objectId","GameId",....]   <-- List Of String
```

Thus I tried the code here:

```
def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
                yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x
```

However, it can only find the special key's value, but cannot set the range (what I mean by range is that the first "`{}`" as array 0 + the second "`{}`" as array 1+ the "fields" in classLevelPermissions won't be involved in the result, in some sense I guess is the depth level ). I still cannot resolve the problem and get what I want.

How can I set the depth and put to corresponding array e.g. [0],[1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [
    {   'className': 'BoardGame', 
        'fields': {
            'objectId': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'playerName': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'cheatMode': {'type': 'Boolean'}, 
            'score': {'type': 'Number'}, 
            'updatedAt': {'type': 'Date'}, 
            'createdAt': {'type': 'Date'}
        }, 
        'classLevelPermissions': {
            'addField': {'*': True}, 
            'create': {'*': True}, 'get': {'*': True}, 
            'update': {'*': True}, 'find': {'*': True}, 
            'delete': {'*': True}
        }
    }, 
    {   'className': 'RPGGAme', 
        'fields': {
            'objectId': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'GameId': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'robotName': {'type': 'String'}, 
            'updatedAt': {'type': 'Date'}, 
            'createdAt': {'type': 'Date'}
        }, 
        'classLevelPermissions': {
            'addField': {'*': True}, 
            'create': {'*': True}, 'get': {'*': True}, 
            'fields': {'*': True}, 'find': {'*': True}, 
            'delete': {'*': True}
        }
    }
]
```

Try this:

```
oput = {}
for idx, dict in enumerate(data):
    oput[idx] = {}
    oput[idx]["className"] = dict["className"]
    oput[idx]["fields"] = dict["fields"].keys()
```

then:

```
oput[0]["className"]
>> 'BoardGame'

oput[0]["fields"]
>>  ['objectId', 'playerName', 'cheatMode', 'score', 'updatedAt', 'createdAt']

oput[1]["className"]
>> 'RPGGAme'

oput[1]["fields"]
>> ['robotName', 'GameId', 'createdAt', 'objectId', 'updatedAt']
```